# Saving profile with registration in Django-Registration

Tags: django, profile, registration

In Django-Registration it says you can save a custom profile when you save a user.
But I have no idea what the documentation is asking me to do.  Here is what they say:

> To enable creation of a custom user profile along with the `User` (e.g., the model specified in the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting), define a function which knows how to create and save an instance of that model with appropriate default values, and pass it as the keyword argument `profile_callback`. This function should accept one keyword argument:
>
> `user`
>
> The `User` to relate the profile to.

Can someone give me an example of the function that needs to be created and how to pass it as a argument?

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the callback function in your urls.py file.

```
from mysite.profile.models import UserProfile


url( r'^accounts/register/$',      'registration.views.register',
        { 'profile_callback': UserProfile.objects.create }, name = 'registration_register' ),
```

Substitute your own function for UserProfile.objects.create as needed.

Comment: Well, i need to do the same...but i can undestand how ill show the profile form in the sample place of the register form and save the data... i dont know im lost...thanks

Comment: This is no longer the case in django-registration 0.8+

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in [this blogpost](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/) and expanded on in my answer to [another question on the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100521/django-registration-and-multiple-profiles/5581313#5581313)

django-registration sends a signal at various events happening - registration and activation. At either of those points you can create a hook to that signal which will be given the user and request objects - from there you can create a profile for that user.

The signal from django-registration

```
#registration.signals.py 
user_registered = Signal(providing_args=["user", "request"])
```

Code to create profile

```
#signals.py (in your project)
user_registered.connect(create_profile)

def create_profile(sender, instance, request, **kwargs):
    from myapp.models import Profile
    #If you want to set any values (perhaps passed via request) 
    #you can do that here

    Profile(user = instance).save()
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who met this problem, I think this blog post is a good tutorial: http://johnparsons.net/index.php/2013/06/28/creating-profiles-with-django-registration/.