# django-registration: Where should I put the "registration" directory?

Tags: django, git, django-models, django-forms, django-registration

I'm using the django-registration app from https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/, and I'm a bit confused as to where I should place it.

I've added "registration" under INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py (as instructed), but shouldn't the **registration** app mentioned *be in my project directory*, with all my other apps? This seems to make more sense to me than having it somewhere else (ie. PYTHONPATH).

So, I'm thinking of cloning the repo, just grabbing django-registration's **registration** app, abandoning all the other files included in django-registration (INSTALL, README, docs, etc.), and sticking that **registration** app in my project directory.

This way, I can edit the models to include more fields, reflect that in the forms, etc.

---

Is this wrong?

(Sorry, it's my first large Django project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't touch the files of `django-registration` - if you want to add your own custom fields for a user profile, you'd do something like this:

[Saving profile with registration in Django-Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072270/saving-profile-with-registration-in-django-registration)

Answer (score 0):

When you install a django package, this package are on your PYTHONPATH, so your project **see** it.

So just [install via pip](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/quickstart.html#automatic-installation-via-a-package-manager) or easy_install (pip is better), and [put on settings' INSTALLED_APPS the 'registration' package](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/quickstart.html#required-settings)

Follow [this instructions](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/quickstart.html)