# django-registration app and Django 1.5 custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I use django-registration app and Django 1.5. How to create (new in django) custom user model and save also this data during registration (Please note that I am using django-registration):

```
class CustomProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072270/saving-profile-with-registration-in-django-registration

Comment: @rafek I try with new custom user model (new in Django 1.5)

Answer (score 9):

django-registration's main fork is not compatible with django 1.5 for now.

Check [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/36/fixes-for-15-use-templateview-and-the-new/diff).

You have three options:

- Patch django-registration's code. You can get the changes needed from the pull request.
- Use an unofficial fork that is already patched. [This one](https://bitbucket.org/LinnTroll/django-registration-1.5) for example.
- Wait for an update on the main fork...

Comment: I just downloaded the current "trunk" version of the `django-registration` app from bitbucket, and it works with Django 1.5 (it did not work when I used `pip` to install the app). The version number I downloaded is `VERSION = (0, 9, 0, 'beta', 1)`.

Comment: maybe `django-registration2` ? I've just installed it instead `django-registration` because `yolk -V django-registration` gives only `django-registration 0.8` which is not compatible with Django==1.5.1

Answer (score 4):

This [link](http://johnparsons.net/index.php/2013/06/28/creating-profiles-with-django-registration/#comment-456)  explains the process well and works with django-registration 1.0

here are a few extra pointers in addition to the above code.

To update the first name change this in the models.py

```
def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
profile = ExUserProfile(user = user)
profile.is_human = bool(request.POST["is_human"])
user.first_name = request.POST["firstname"]
user.save()
profile.save()

user_registered.connect(user_registered_callback)
```

and in the forms.py file

```
class ExRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    is_human = forms.BooleanField(label = "Are you human?:")
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

finally to see the changes on the form create an appropriate template. The profile can be seen in the admin by creating a file called admin.py in your app and write the following code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from prof.models import ExUserProfile

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ExUserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Won't this actually create both a User and ExUserProfile instance?

Comment: Yes, that is objective the custom user model is created by associating the ExUserProfile to the user object and saving the necessary fields

Answer (score 0):

Django-registration 1.0 has been released recently. It was completely rewritten to use class based views and with Django 1.0 custom user model support. Check out the [docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/).