# Subclassing django-registration 1.0 forms for django 1.5 custom user models

Tags: django, django-registration, django-1.5

django-registration 1.0 now has support for django 1.5 custom user models. The django-registration documentation only has the following FAQ item about it:

> **I’m using Django 1.5 and a custom user model; how do I make that work?**
>
> Although the two built-in backends supplied with
>   django-registration both assume Django’s default User model, the base
>   view classes are deliberately user-model-agnostic. Simply subclass
>   them, and implement logic for your custom user model.

I'm not sure which views I need to subclass and what should go in them. I've also noticed that the `ProfileManager` in django-registration still assumes a separate username field.

In my specific case, I've removed the 'username' field, added a 'display_name', and made 'email' the identifying field:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="Email Address",
        max_length=384,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Without subclassing any django-registration classes, the default rendering of the registration form pulls in fields from `User` instead of `MyUser`.

I've seen the following SO thread [django-registration app and Django 1.5 custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296295/django-registration-app-and-django-1-5-custom-user-model), but it didn't help.

**Update**

I've noticed that RegistrationForm is hardcoded with a 'username' field. The FAQ only mentions subclassing the backend, so I'm not sure what the intention is here. Should I subclass the form as well?

Comment: Please have a look at this commit - https://bitbucket.org/LinnTroll/django-registration-1.5/commits/c71d5b8e273551cffdfc7869545430e3 !!

You need to subclass `DefaultBackend`, `RegistrationFormFromUserModel` as well as `RegistrationManager` for this.

Comment: Have you changed AUTH_USER_MODEL to the new custom user model in settings.py?

Comment: What'd you end up doing? I'm thinking about just handling this but explicitly defining the fields in the registration form instead of just using the `form` template tag. Not ideal, but I think it might be the simplest option.

Comment: i just performed a find and replace for the particular application and replaced all instances with my custom user model and fields. Not elegant but I found it fairly effective

Comment: @jon did you find the solution. I am having similar problem. can you post what you did to make it work? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I never found a solution, and the project I was working on no longer exists. I've added a bounty for you so it gets more attention (bye-bye reputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts are most definitely not Django 1.5 compatible yet: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/forms.py?at=default#cl-48

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean_username(self):
        # ...
        # The line below needs fixing
        existing = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
```

So unless those methods are changed and/or you subclass them, it won't work yet.

For your specific case this registration form should do the trick:

```
from registration import forms as registration_forms
from django.contrib import auth

class RegistrationForm(registration_forms.RegistrationForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        '''
        Validate that the username is alphanumeric and is not already
        in use.
        '''
        User = auth.get_user_model()
        existing = User.objects.filter(display_name__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that name already exists."))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
```

In addition to a custom property on your model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ...

    def get_username(self):
        return self.display_name

    def set_username(self, username):
        self.display_name = username

    def del_username(self):
        del self.display_name

    username = property(get_username, set_username, del_username)
```